# documentation on display: -webkit-inline-box;

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I'd love to find out more details about the -webkit-inline-box property but I can't seem to find anything anywhere. I tried the normal channels of w3c, google, css-tricks bug I'm not coming up with anything. I'm thinking that it's old inherited code from flexbox.

Does anyone know the details of...

```
display: -webkit-inline-box;
```

?

Comment: it's inline-block now according to this http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/moz-inline-box I would think webkit is the same

Comment: @Huangism: That was a much older incarnation of `-moz-inline-box`, probably back when `inline-block` wasn't standardized yet. No other vendor implemented anything like that - they shot straight for `inline-block` (and WebKit was still KHTML at the time). Apparently `-moz-inline-box` was later recycled for one of the older flexbox specifications, presumably the same one `-webkit-inline-box` refers to.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I'm thinking that it's old inherited code from flexbox.

You're correct.

Flexible boxes, defined by `display: box` and `display: inline-box` respectively, were old incarnations of what are now known as flex containers (`display: flex` and `display: inline-flex`).

They are described in [this version of the Flexbox spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723), but it doesn't say anything about these two `display` values other than

> In CSS, flexible boxes (often referred to only as boxes in this specification) may be created by setting the ‘display’ property. A block-level box can be specified with a value of ‘box’ and an inline box can be specified using a value of inline-box.

Everything else is described by the `box-*` properties in the rest of that document.

Implementations and production sites still exist that use the old flexbox code, but it goes without saying that you should never have to use them today. Focus on writing CSS according to [the latest Flexbox spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox), which enjoys [reasonable support by modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) and is on track for standardization.

Comment: Oddly just came across this question thinking it was a flex as you say but when I apply flex or inline-flex instead it doesn't behave the same way as using -webkit-inline-box kind of weird.