# Different browsers (display: -webkit-inline-box;)

Tags: css, browser

I have a CSS code:

```
.tudo ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
```

But Mozilla Firefox doesn't read the:

```
display: -webkit-inline-box;
```

Can I set different displays for each browser? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: That's a very old syntax - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732651/documentation-on-display-webkit-inline-box

Answer (score 1):

All browser use some prefix for "beta" (usually this prefix disappear with the most recent versions of the browsers) CSS style for example `-webkit` is for Chrome, Opera and Safari but `-moz` is for Mozzilla Firefox and one vendor prefix doesn't run on other browser, you can see most used prefix [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).

When you write some CSS I advice you not to use any vendor prefix but auto-prefix your file when you finish your progect with an online service like [Pleeease.io](http://pleeease.io/play/). You can also use a preprocessor like [Prepos](https://prepros.io) to automatic prefix CSS on save.

This is an example using [Pleeease.io](http://pleeease.io/play/):

INPUT

```
.a {
 display: flex;
 background: linear-gradient(red, green);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
.a {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, green);
 background: linear-gradient(red, green);
}
```