# CSS Safari 14 issues with child elements blowing out in heigh when contained within a grid within a flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari, grid

In the following markup below `Col1` and `Col2` inside the `grid` will blow out in height on MacOS Safari 14. What's interesting is that it blows out (off screen) by the exact height of the div above the grid. Is this a Safari bug and are there any work arounds OR have I missed something in my CSS?

Screenshot from MacOS Safari 14
[image: Screenshot from MacOS Safari 14]

Screenshot from Chrome
[image: Screenshot from Chrome]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-full">
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .h-full {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .h-10 {
        height: 2.5rem;
      }
      .min-h-0 {
        min-height: 0;
      }
      .flex {
        display: flex;
      }
      .flex-col {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .flex-auto {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
      }
      .grid {
        display:grid;
      }
      .grid-cols-3{
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr))
      }
      .col-span-1{
        grid-column: span 1 / span 1;
      }
      .flex-initial {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
      }
      .bg-green {
        background-color: rgb(12, 236, 12);
      }
      .bg-pink {
        background-color: rgb(248, 47, 255);
      }
      .bg-blue {
        background-color: rgb(110, 230, 252);
      }
      .bg-yellow {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="h-full">
    <div id="sapper" class="h-full">
      <div class="flex flex-col h-full">
        <header class="flex-initial">
          Navigation
        </header>
        <main class="flex-auto h-full flex flex-col">
          <div class="flex-initial h-10 bg-yellow">
            Middle
          </div>
          <div class=" bg-pink grid grid-cols-3 flex-auto min-h-0">
            <div class="col-span-1 bg-green">Col 1</div>
            <div class="col-span-1 bg-blue">Col 2</div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, there's a couple of spelling mistakes in your code (flex-inital/flex-initial) but sadly correcting these didn't solve your problem, I just though you'd like to know in case they affect something else. I found a workaround to the overflow problem which seems OK in Safari, see answer, but please treat with caution as I don't entirely understand exactly why it works.

Comment: Thanks for that, I corrected the spelling, nothing like posting questions at 1am!

Comment: Thanks for figuring out what was being used to calculate the amount of overflow - had me scratching my head for a few hours. Did you get anywhere? I've got the exact same issue: flex-column parent, with children that are both flex-grow: 1 and also grids. The actual blowout is definitely on the grid children, which seems SO far down the DOM tree to be affected, but there you go...

Comment: @KyleDuncan I have accepted it as a bug in the Safari implementation at the moment. I couldn't figure out how to raise this with Apple.

Comment: I was trying to raise the bug through Apple support, it turns out that's the wrong place, instead it should be raised at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com. I have opened a case but there's not a public link to that case from what I can see. I will reply to this question with the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this on Safari 14.1.1 and the issue appears to have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the given code on IOS 14 Safari also gives the overflow problem.

I came across this [documentation on display: -webkit-inline-box;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732651/documentation-on-display-webkit-inline-box) which discussed a (even then) outdated -webkit-inline-box setting.

If you apply this to the div containing the two columns and set each of those columns to 33.33% width (as the repeat(3...) setting seemed to then be being ignored) the correct result is obtained.

This seems rather (well, really) hacky as it's using an outdated setting which seems to just work in Safari -but for how long - and seems not to upset the other browsers.

Tested on Window 10 - Chrome, Edge, Firefox - and on iPadIOS 14 - Safari.

Just in case it is useful to be going on with here is the given code with these two additions (deliberately put in as inline styles to make it clear what has been added).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-full">
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .h-full {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .h-10 {
        height: 2.5rem;
      }
      .min-h-0 {
        min-height: 0;
      }
      .flex {
        display: flex;
      }
      .flex-col {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .flex-auto {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
      }
      .grid {
        display:grid;
      }
      .grid-cols-3{    
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr))
      }
      .flex-inital {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
      }
      .bg-green {
        background-color: rgb(12, 236, 12);
      }
      .bg-pink {
        background-color: rgb(248, 47, 255);
      }
      .bg-blue {
        background-color: rgb(110, 230, 252);
      }
      .bg-yellow {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="h-full">
    <div id="sapper" class="h-full">
      <div class="flex flex-col h-full">
        <header class="flex-initial">
          Navigation
        </header>
        <main class="flex-auto h-full flex flex-col">
          <div class="flex-inital h-10 bg-yellow">
            Middle
          </div>
          <div class=" bg-pink grid grid-cols-3 flex-auto min-h-0" style="display:-webkit-inline-box;">
            <div class=" bg-green" style="width:33.33%;">Col 1</div>
            <div class=" bg-blue" style="width:33.33%;">Col 2</div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried out the fix but it's not compatible with `grid-column: span 1 / span 1;` on the child divs of the div with the grid class. `display:-webkit-inline-box;` overrides the `display:grid`